# F# List.map type error

Tags: f#

For F# since I can't use if statements inside List.map, I tried to use a helper function. If all the values  y, and z are bigger or less than the median it will return all the values  y, z as either c1 or c2. But I got type error in line 12, where let L = "..." for "10 20" it says "expected type unit but given type int". Not quite sure on how to fix this. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
       let hold y z median c1 c2 =
           if  (y > median) && (z > median) then
             (c1, c1)
           else if  (y <= median) && (z <= median) then
             (c2, c2)
       //line 10
       let holder =
           let L = L |> List.map (fun (y,z) -> (hold y z median 10 20, hold y z median 10 20) 
           L
```

Comment: you are missing the `else` add `else 0` to `hold`. In F# if-else is an expression not a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to achiveve as the code and the logic doesn't line up. However you need to take into consideration the case, when your `if` doesn't match, and you branch to `else`. This has to be the same type, as the `if` branch for obvious reason. If you omit it, it will be `unit`.

```
let hold y z median c1 c2 =            
        if  ((y > median) && (z > median)) then (c1,c1)
        elif ((y <= median) && (z <= median)) then (c2,c2)
        else (y,z)

let holder xs median =
    xs |> List.map (fun (y,z) -> (hold y z median 10 20, hold y z median 10 20, hold y z median 10  20)) 

let xs = [(20,40);(1,2)]
let med = 10

holder xs med
```

You can also use `match` to describe this logic. But if we stick to the `if` nothing stops you using it within the `List.map`. Here's an example:

```
xs
|> List.map (fun (x,y) ->
                          if x > 10 then (x , x)
                          elif y >= 10 then (y , y)
                          else (x,y) )
```

To be honest, if it's complex you are right to factor it out.